# Varios Modelos 3D con un image target

Tags: unity3d, vuforia

No puedo lograr esta tarea, Tengo 6 modelos diferentes que tienen el mismo target, pero quiero que aparezca solo un modelo a la vez, digamos el que esta en la posición [i], ya que lo estoy haciendo con un arreglo de GameObjects, entonces al seleccionar siguiente con una flecha recién me aparezca el siguiente modelo y que ocurra lo mismo con la flecha para atrás, que me despliegue el modelo anterior.

Logro visualizar un modelo pero al ir avanzando con las flechas los demás se quedan también en pantalla, llenándose de los 6 modelos.
El código hasta ahora es el siguiente:

```
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MyDefaultTrackableEventHandler3: MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler {


  protected TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;
  public int s_SelectedIndex;
  public GameObject[] players;

  protected virtual void Start() {

    players = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");

    foreach(GameObject wi in players) {
      wi.SetActive(false);
    }
    mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent < TrackableBehaviour > ();
    if (mTrackableBehaviour)
      mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);

  }

  protected virtual void OnDestroy() {
    if (mTrackableBehaviour)
      mTrackableBehaviour.UnregisterTrackableEventHandler(this);

  }


  public void OnTrackableStateChanged(TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus, TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus) {

    if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED || newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED || newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED) {
      Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " found");
      OnTrackingFound();

    } else if (previousStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED && newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.NO_POSE) {
      Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " lost");
      OnTrackingLost();
    } else {
      OnTrackingLost();
    }
  }


  public void Suma() {
    players[s_SelectedIndex].SetActive(false);
    s_SelectedIndex++;
    players[s_SelectedIndex].SetActive(true);
  } 

  public void Resta() {
    players[s_SelectedIndex].SetActive(false);
    s_SelectedIndex--;
    players[s_SelectedIndex].SetActive(true);
  }


  protected virtual void OnTrackingFound() {



    if (s_SelectedIndex < players.Length) {
      Debug.Log("Player Number " + s_SelectedIndex + " is named " + players[s_SelectedIndex].name);

      var rendererComponents = players[s_SelectedIndex].GetComponentsInChildren < Renderer > (true);
      var colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren < Collider > (true);
      var canvasComponents = GetComponentsInChildren < Canvas > (true);


      foreach(var component in rendererComponents)
      component.enabled = true;


      foreach(var component in colliderComponents)
      component.enabled = true;


      foreach(var component in canvasComponents)
      component.enabled = true;

    }


  }


  protected virtual void OnTrackingLost() {

    var rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren < Renderer > (true);
    var colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren < Collider > (true);
    var canvasComponents = GetComponentsInChildren < Canvas > (true);


    foreach(var component in rendererComponents)
    component.enabled = false;


    foreach(var component in colliderComponents)
    component.enabled = false;


    foreach(var component in canvasComponents)
    component.enabled = false;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba desactivar los gameobjects completos (de no tenerlos enparentados es mejor crear un Empty Object por cada objeto y enparentar los modelos ahí, y desactivar el Empty), desactivar los componentes a veces no funciona bien en Unity. Así mismo te evitas el overhead de tener que encontrar los componentes de cada objeto en cada cambio.

Reemplaza esto:

```
var rendererComponents = players[s_SelectedIndex].GetComponentsInChildren < Renderer > (true);
  var colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren < Collider > (true);
  var canvasComponents = GetComponentsInChildren < Canvas > (true);


  foreach(var component in rendererComponents)
  component.enabled = true;


  foreach(var component in colliderComponents)
  component.enabled = true;


  foreach(var component in canvasComponents)
  component.enabled = true;
```

Por esto:

```
players[s_SelectedIndex].SetActive(true);
```

Y así mismo para la desactivación.